# Find overlapping elements in a list of tuples?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, tuples, intersection

From my understanding of the intersection function, it finds complete overlap between elements in a list. For example:

```
tup_1 = [(1,2,3),(4,5,6)]
tup_2 = [(4,5,6)]
ol_tup = set(tup_1).intersection(tup_2)
print ol_tup
```

would yield:

```
set([(4, 5, 6)])
```

However, suppose my list of tuples are set up as this:

```
tup_1 = [(1,2,3),(4,5,5)]
tup_2 = [(4,5,6)]
```

Where there's an overlap in 2 elements of the 2nd tuple in tup_1 and 1st tuple in tup_2. If I want to python to return these 2 tuples: (4,5,5) and (4,5,6), is there an easier way than this nested for loop (below)?

```
for single_tuple_1 in tup_1:
    for single_tuple_2 in tup_2:
        if single_tuple_1[0] == single_tuple_2[0] and single_tuple_1[1] == single_tuple_2[1]:
            print single_tuple_1,single_tuple_2
```

EDIT:

For this case, suppose order matters and suppose the tuples contain 5 elements:

```
tup_1 = [(1,2,3,4,5),(4,5,6,7,8),(11,12,13,14,15)]
tup_2 = [(1,2,3,4,8),(4,5,1,7,8),(11,12,13,14,-5)]
```

And I would like to find the tuples that intersect with each other in their respective first 4 elements. So the result should be:

```
[(1,2,3,4,5),(1,2,3,4,8),(11,12,13,14,15),(11,12,13,14,-5)]
```

How would the code change to accommodate this?

Comment: Does `tup_2`  always contain a single tuple?

Comment: What if the element overlaps with two others? Would you print two pairs? In this case, I think there's no faster way than quadratic, i.e. comparing each pair.

Comment: Also, does position of elements within the tuple matter?

Comment: Do you always want to check for exactly two in common? What if there's more than that?

Comment: Did one of the solutions below help? Feel free to accept one if it did (green tick on left), or ask for clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to return all the pairs of "overlapping" tuples there's no way around comparing all the pairs, i.e. a quadratic algorithm. But you could make the code a bit more elegant using a list comprehension, [`product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) for the combinations and `zip` and `sum` for the comparison:

```
>>> tup_1 = [(1,2,3),(4,5,5),(7,8,9)]

>>> tup_2 = [(4,5,6),(0,5,5),(9,8,7)]

>>> [(a, b) for (a, b) in itertools.product(tup_1, tup_2)
...         if sum(1 for ai, bi in zip(a, b) if ai == bi) >= 2]
[((4, 5, 5), (4, 5, 6)), ((4, 5, 5), (0, 5, 5))]
```

Note: This checks whether two tuples have the same element in at least two positions, i.e. order matters. If order should not matter, you can convert `a` and `b` to `set` instead and check the size of their intersection, but that might fail for repeated numbers, i.e. the intersection of `(1,1,2)` and `(1,1,3)` would just be `1` instead of `2`.

If you only want to match the first two, or first two and last two elements, you can compare slices of the tuples in an accordant disjunction:

```
>>> [(a, b) for (a, b) in itertools.product(tup_1, tup_2)
...         if a[:2] == b[:2]]
[((4, 5, 5), (4, 5, 6))]

>>> [(a, b) for (a, b) in itertools.product(tup_1, tup_2)
...         if a[:2] == b[:2] or a[-2:] == b[-2:]]
[((4, 5, 5), (4, 5, 6)), ((4, 5, 5), (0, 5, 5))]
```

Comment: If I only wanted to match the first 2 elements of each tuple or last 2 each tuple, would I have to add the index brackets in a/b,ai/bi, or neither of those variables?

Answer (score 2):

This is one way using a list comprehension. The logic as written checks for an overlap of at least 2 elements.

Note that if there is *no* overlap you will be left with the one element of `tup_2`, but that can be trivially identified.

```
from itertools import chain

tup_1 = [(1,2,3),(4,5,5)]
tup_2 = [(4,5,6)]

y = sorted(tup_2[0])
res = [i for i in chain(tup_1, tup_2) if
       sum(i==j for i, j in zip(sorted(i), y)) > 1]

print res

[(4, 5, 5), (4, 5, 6)]
```

Comment: Note that using `set` might fail if the tuples have repeated elements.